# Join Date and Text

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tables:

Table1

| ItemNo | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-28 |
| CDF | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-28 |
| HIJ | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-28 |
| KLM | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-31 |
| NOP | 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-31 |
| QRS | 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-31 |

Table2

| Date | ItemNo |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | ABC |
| 2023-01-01 | EFG |
| 2023-01-01 | HIJ |
| 2023-01-02 | ABC |
| 2023-01-02 | EFG |
| 2023-01-03 | QRS |
| 2023-02-04 | QRS |

I would like to join the two table somehow

Example:

CASE
WHEN Table2.date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
AND Table2.itemNo = Table1.itemNo
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END

I would like a Y N flag in Table 2 based on the criteria of Table1.

Table1 has a start and end date and itemno. Thats the criteria.

Its just not working for me. Some rows I get Y some rows N, even though I have filtered the dates by 2023-01-01 and 2023-02-28.

And my rows triple

Comment: Can you add a sample of the expected output? How you are joining the two tables?

Comment: Do you want each item (or record) to have each `Date`'s results? Since table 1 is not unique by `ItemNo`, it is hard to guess your expected results.

Comment: p.s. I would recommend you not use reserved keywords (such as `Date`) as column names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SELECT 
    Table2.Date, 
    Table2.ItemNo, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Table2.Date BETWEEN Table1.startDate AND Table1.endDate AND Table2.ItemNo = Table1.ItemNo THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N' 
    END AS Flag
FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1
    ON Table2.ItemNo = Table1.ItemNo
```